# Migrating phpMyAdmin database to Windows Azure for CakePHP web application

Tags: mysql, cakephp, azure, phpmyadmin, azure-sql-database

My problem is pretty specific and I have been having trouble finding an answer on the web. I have been building a CakePHP web application locally and hosting it locally on an Apache server with phpMyAdmin using XAMPP. Now I'm trying to migrate the site to Windows Azure and the database import is proving problematic.

I created a new website in Azure and placed my website root folder in the indicated directory. I published the site and was able to view the site with the expected "missing database" errors.

I then exported all my tables in phpMyAdmin to .sql files (some were hosted on another server so I couldnt export the entire database) and now I have a problem. I googled how to import .sql files extensively but was only able to find how to import from SQL Server. I came across an article on a Microsoft site:

http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2012/12/17/phpmyadmin-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx

I followed the steps but was unable to login at the final stage. However, this method seems like overkill, surely there is a simple way to import something as fundamental as a standard MySQL database into Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it through the command line. Read this:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/tutorials/website-w-mysql-and-git/

Pay attention to the section titled "Get remote MySQL connection information". Once the mysql database is created on Azure, connect to it from mysql:

```
mysql -h{Data Source] -u[User Id] -p[Password] -D[Database]
```

From here, you could copy the create table statements and insert statements from the sql file you created. Or, if you can navigate to the .sql file you can do something like this:

```
mysql>\. data.sql
```

This will execute all of the commands in the sql file.

Comment: I'm sure this works but since i don't have that many tables and I'm not very adept with SQL or Azure I ended up manually making the tables.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler approach; to summarise before going into the details: You can access your remote azure MySQL database from your local phpmyadmin and use the import, export - all the functions you're used to using on phpmyadmin.

The basis for the method i'm talking about can be found here:
http://ruslany.net/2012/12/phpmyadmin-on-windows-azure-web-sites/
This approach allows you to install phpmyadmin on your azure website so that you can access it via something like www.yoursitename.net/phpmyadmin

However, an even better approach than that is to access your remote (Azure) mysql database directly from your existing local phpmyadmin - seeing that you are using xampp. To do so, look in your xampp/phpmyadmin folder for config.inc.php and add the following lines at the end of the file:

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = "[look for data source in mysqldbconnectionstring - see in your azure dashboard publish settings]";
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = 'false';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassord'] = false;
```

- so change only the host value - see instruction in [] above. Save the file.

When you open phpmyadmin from localhost, you will see that 'server choice' is now a drop-down - you know what to do!

Comment: but doing from local to remote, is a bit more slower because of connection not being direct

Comment: It's the same as any work you do on a remote server. We can't ever get the same speed through a remote server as you get on a localhost. The reason I find this approach useful is that you can perform remote db operations from the same environment that you use for local test development.

Comment: I am getting SSL errors when trying to log in...do you know how to fix this?